# Mejor forma para encapsular componentes Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, aplicación-web

Mi pregunta es la siguiente ¿De qué forma puedo colocar mi router outlet para un componente específico que no quiero que esté en una ruta

Ejemplo, esta es la vista de la página principal

[image: Home view]

Y para esa forma uso algo simple

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
<scroll-to-top></scroll-to-top>
```

Pero para otras vistas que incluyen un componente adicional preferiría usar este

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <widgets></widgets>
  </div>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
<scroll-to-top></scroll-to-top>
```

Para que se viera de la siguiente forma

[image: Blog view]

Uso `<widgets></widgets>` que es un componente aparte, y había decidido ponerlo en el `app.component.html` para que al cambiar a las demás páginas no recargara el componente cuando tenga las consultas implementadas.

¿Existe alguna forma dinámica en la que se pueda hacer esto?

Comment: Hola, ¿Quiere mostrar un componente(widgets) solo en algunas páginas?

Comment: ->Puedes como dices colocarlo en el app.component con *ngIf verificando la ruta
->Puedes usar loadChildren en tus rutas principales donde el componente llame a un <router-outlet></router-outlet>(Aquí se mostrarían todas la rutas registradas en loadChildren)<widgets></widgets>

Comment: Sí, hice eso. Hice una función que valida un arreglo comparando las rutas return this.avoidUrls.some(url => this._router.url.startsWith(url)); @UrielManzano si quieres ponlo como respuesta :) Muchas gracias por tu tiempo